# If you execute a program on a server with SSH will it continue to run after I disconnect?

Tags: ssh, drush

What I want to do is connect to my server and have Drush (a Drupal command-line program) run a command to start a large data import. To do this I need to SSH into the server first. So I would execute the Drush call. Then I want to be able to shut down my computer and walk away.

Will this continue to run if I do this? Someone has suggested to me that I can just put an ampersand at the end of the command and it will put the command in the background. Will that work?

The reason I ask instead of just test is because this will be a large amount of data and I don't want to start it before I am entirely ready to put it on the server.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should also take a look at *screen*.

What you need to know now about screen is that it emulates a terminal that may be detached and retached.

To detach press *Ctrl+A,D* (Control plus A, release both, then D).

And run the command *screen -x* to attach again.

http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/

More usefull commands:

```
screen -list        shows all active screens
screen -r NUMBER    retach to the screen corresponding to NUMBER
```

Comment: And that would work on a Linux server that I SSH into and have no control of the installed packages??? If so then how would it be able to keep track of which process that I am reattaching after I log out and then back in?

Comment: It is very probable that screen is already installed. Most sysadmins I know would consider it madness to set up any server _without_ having screen available.

Comment: So it turns out that my server admin just sent me an article that details how to use screen for this. Ok then, screen it is.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
nohup yourcommand &
```

to do this

Comment: That looks really familiar. A long long time ago I setup a PHP script to just launch a command line command and continue without waiting for it to finish and I think that this is exactly what I used. Thanks man!